# imap_mail_move not working

Tags: php, email, imap

I have written a class to connect to my mailbox and move the spam to my junk folder. It doesn't seem to be working though and I don't know why. Here is what I have:

```
<?php
$cleaner = new Mail_cleaner();

echo 'Deleted '.$cleaner->deleted.' files';

Class Mail_cleaner {

public $server = '{mail.gridhost.co.uk:993/imap/ssl}';
public $folder = 'INBOX';
public $user = 'email@domain.com';
public $password = 'password';

public $mailbox;
public $check;
public $thelist;
public $overviews;
public $ids = array();
public $deleted = 0;

function __construct() {
    $this->open_connection();
    $this->get_messages();
}

function get_messages() {
    $this->ids = array();
    $this->overviews = imap_fetch_overview($this->mailbox,"1:{$this->check->Nmsgs}");

    foreach($this->overviews as $overview) {
        //print_r($overview); exit;
        if(stripos($overview->subject, 'SPAM')!==FALSE
        || stripos($overview->subject, 'Luxury Replicas')!==FALSE
        || stripos($overview->subject, 'Pharmacy')!==FALSE
        || stripos($overview->subject, 'viagra')!==FALSE
        || stripos($overview->subject, 'dr.maxman')!==FALSE
        || stripos($overview->subject, 'cialis')!==FALSE
        || stripos($overview->subject, 'penis enlarge')!==FALSE
        || stripos($overview->from, 'westin')!==FALSE
        || stripos($overview->from, 'rightmove')!==FALSE
        || stripos($overview->from, 'groupon')!==FALSE
        || stripos($overview->from, 'primelocation')!==FALSE
        || stripos($overview->from, 'mg-rover')!==FALSE
        ) {
            $this->ids[] = $overview->uid;

        }
    }
    if(count($this->ids) > 0) {
        $this->move_and_delete();
    }
}

function move_and_delete() {
    foreach($this->ids as $id) {
        // move to junk
        $result = imap_mail_move($this->mailbox, $id, 'INBOX.Junk');

        if($result) {
            //imap_delete($this->mailbox, $id); 
            $this->deleted++;
        }
    }
    imap_expunge($this->mailbox);
    imap_close($this->mailbox);
}

function open_connection() {
    $this->mailbox = imap_open($this->server.$this->folder, $this->user, $this->password);
    $this->check = imap_check($this->mailbox);
    $this->thelist = imap_getmailboxes($this->mailbox, $this->server, "*");
}

}
?>
```

I get the same output each time saying deleted 115 messages. If i run it twice in quick succession then the output the second time should be deleted 0 messages. So basically it's not moving them properly because they are not disappearing from the inbox into the junk. Anyone know why? It is getting all the messages and looping through them but it seems the move just isnt happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all I am wondering that you add the UIDs to your array, but you try to delete from the message sequence. You will need to add the options parameter (CP_UID) to your call of imap_mail_move.
`$result = imap_mail_move($this->mailbox, $id, 'INBOX.Junk', CP_UID);`
That might also be the reason why your expunge does not work, since it might not have moved any message anyway. What is the value of $result during your tries?
Since you close your mailbox at the end, you could expunge on close by using `imap_close($this->mailbox, CL_EXPUNGE)`.
Hope that helps,
Stefan